# How to paste a table into RichTextBox from Word file(DOC/DOCX)

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

Need help.
Please suggest how to copy a table from dox or docx file and paste the same into richtextbox.I am getting only the texts not the table or lines.Please help...

Answer (score 0):

1.make sure you are using RichTextbox control from developer tab
2.select your whole richtextbox control first and then go to Insert tab-> create table

enjoy !!!

Comment: if that not work just press enter to go the next line and after that create the table. one more way create the table outside the control and paste if afterwards

Comment: Thanks but that is not the problem.We can create table inside richtextbox I know.I am asking how to copy a table from word document(create a table inside word document then copy the table and paste it in richtextbox control)??...When I am trying to paste in richtextbox the table and data inside table are getting separated.I want the correct format as in word document.

Comment: Well I am able to copy paste the table inside the rich textbox control with all the formatting it has.
one more thing to try when you paste there are options  1)default paste 2) Merge Formatting 3) Keep Source formatting
I've selected 3rd option.

will you able to clarify or put some screenshots so that I can help you?